# Does a simple copper wire with an AC current create EM waves?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, radio, antennas

I want to know if a household AC current flowing through a simple copper wire will radiate EM waves? If yes, up to what range and can they be called radio waves?

Comment: yes, it does radiate, the frequency is low and it does broadly  fall into the radio wave definition http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremely_low_frequency

Comment: power from antenna falls as 1/r^2 http://www.cv.nrao.edu/course/astr534/AntennaTheory.html

Answer (score 1):

As [anna](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/1492/anna-v) said in comments

AC current at typical frequencies of 50 or 60 Hz does produce electromagnetic waves. those frequencies are classified as [extremely low frequencies (ELF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremely_low_frequency)

The energy in these radio waves will be only a tiny fraction of the energy flowing in† the wire.

The strength of electromagnetic waves diminishes with distance according to an inverse square law. So the strength 1 meter away is one millionth of the strength at 1 millimeter away.

---

† figuratively.

Answer (score 0):

Surely it will, since the only condition for an electromagnetic wave is a changeing magnetic and electric field,,, it can be called Really large wavelength and low energy radiation, but to call it radio waves would means radio detectors should detect it which means you need a powerful supply and a high frequency one